# How to add additional custom headers while throwing exception to store the message in dlq on kafka?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a consumer application that listens a kafka topic, on exception it sends the record to the dlq(dead-letter-queue) as expected.

Before throwing Exception iam setting the header in the consumer application and it is getting set but it is not sent to the dead-letter topic, the dead-letter topic only have the inbuilt headers like 'x-exception-message', 'x-original-partition' etc.. and not the one that i set.

Below is the piece of code in my Consumer application:

```
modifiedMessage = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(consumedMessage).setHeader("x-ecode", new Integer(100)).setHeader(BinderHeaders.PARTITION_OVERRIDE,consumedMessage.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID)).build();
System.out.println("error header:"+modifiedMessage.getHeaders().get("x-ecode",Integer.class)); //100
throw new RuntimeException(modifiedMessage.toString());
```

> **Note:** Iam setting the x-code in my application.yml under
>   spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.header=x-ecode

In the above piece of code am able to set the header, and actually verified that it is set but it is not sent to dead-letter topic..

The payload is getting sent correctly, How can i send that header to the dead letter topic? do i need to add any properties in my application.yml to enable it sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are doing there is creating a new message and discarding it (except you are setting the exception message as its string implementation.

This will not modify the original inbound message.

You can simply add a new output binding and send the modified message to it yourself.

Or, if you are only adding a constant, you can add a `ChannelInterceptor` to the binding's error channel and modify the message there. If you need to pass state to the interceptor you could use a custom exception.

However, the simplest solution is to just publish the message yourself instead of using the binder's DLQ mechanism. You already have logic to create the message so it would be just `myCustomDlqBinding.send(modifiedMessage)` (also adding the standard DLQ headers too).

Comment: Thanks Gary, I understood it, one more thing, the message is retried 3 times after throwing exception, how can i disable this behaviour in spring cloud stream kafka?

Comment: When i try out the property 'spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.maxAttempts=1', it is not working and the failed message is processed 3 times

Comment: I found the exact property 'spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.maxAttempts=1' and it is working properly

Comment: @GaryRussel regarding "message modifying" part - both available methods with exceptions as their parameters are of void type (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/support/ChannelInterceptor.html), so how is it possible to enhance a message with a custom exception?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on 3 year old answers. Those methods are not intended to mutate the message, only the `preSend` and `postReceive` can do that. The others are notifications only (success or failure).